# Is there something wrong about my solution to $\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I'm trying to find the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)} dx$. This is my solution:

$\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)} dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{4})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \csc(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) dx = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln(\csc(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) + \cot(x+\frac{\pi}{4})) $.

I used WolframAlpha to differentiate this result to check if I get the integrand and I got it.

However, when I query WolframAlpha to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)} dx$ itself, [the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(cos(x)%20%2B%20sin(x))) looks (is?) very different (involves complex numbers too), which makes me doubt the correctness of my solution. Is there something wrong about my method?

Comment: From the alternate forms, we see that the solution is real.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. The one provided by Wolfram Alpha is correct, but I think that your answer is better, since it provides an answer which uses only real numbers to a question which uses only real numbers too.